# There is a way to select the time elapsed in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an example table (don't mind the column names)

[image]

I want to find a effective way to select the elapsed time between value is 1 and 0 as this:
2021-02-15 12:32:47.000-2021-02-15 13:33:08.000= 1 hour approx,  and so on.

thanks in advance with a method to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they are interleaved, you can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second, date, next_date) / (60.0 * 60) as decimal_hours
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where value = 1;
```

If you want the total, use aggregation:

```
select sum(datediff(second, date, next_date) / (60.0 * 60)) as decimal_hours
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where value = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking